# Azure policy audit classic SQL vulnerability assessment

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I am trying to audit classic SQL vulnerability assessment with Azure policy but I cannot get the policyrule to work. I can get all by using this:

```
"policyRule": {
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Sql/servers"
      },
      {
        "field": "kind",
        "notContains": "analytics"
      }
    ]
  },
```

But if I add:

```
      {
        "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/vulnerabilityAssessments/recurringScans.isEnabled",
        "notEquals": "true"
      }
```

The policy does not detect any resources. This is a correct policyalias but why is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

> The policy does not detect any resources. This is a correct policyalias but why is it not working?

I have used below `Azure Policy` to audit `SQL vulnerability`  assessment.

```json
        {
        "properties": {
        "displayName": "SQL-vulnerability assessment on your sql servers_1.0",
        "policyType": "Custom",
        "mode": "All",
        "parameters": {
        "allowedLocations": {
        "type": "Array",
        },
        "tagname": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Exclusion Tag Name",
        "description": "Rule is not deployed if this tag exists on the SQL Server"
        }
        },
        "effect": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Effect",
        "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
        "AuditIfNotExists",
        "Disabled"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "AuditIfNotExists"
        }
        },
        "policyRule": {
        "if": {
        "allOf": [ 
        {
        "field": "type", 
        "equals": "Microsoft.Sql/servers" 
        },
        {
        "field": "location",
        "in": "[parameters('allowedLocations')]"
        },
        {
        "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagname'), ']')]",
        "exists": "false"
        },
        {
        "value": "[resourceGroup().tags[parameters('tagname')]]",
        "equals": ""
        },
        {
        "value": "[subscription().tags[parameters('tagname')]]",
        "equals": ""    
           }
            ]
      },
        "then": {
        "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
        "details": {
         "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/vulnerabilityAssessments",
        "name": "default",
        "existenceCondition": {
        "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/vulnerabilityAssessments/recurringScans.isEnabled", 
        "equals": "True"
        } 
        }
         }
        }
        }, 
        "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementgroups/48fed3a1-0814-4847-88ce-b766155f2792/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/410c2966a1e1856e",
        "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
        "name": "410c2966a1e1856e"
        }
```

Once  apply policy, it will evaluate your `SQL servers` based on the specified conditions and take the defined action if vulnerability assessment is not enabled.

**Policy Compliance Result:**

[image]

Comment: I have not tried it but if I look into the healthy SQL servers where express configuration is applied it seems that the recurring scan is set to false. Which means that the example policy would find all those non-compliant even though these are compliant.